# StackOverflow meet-up in London, UK

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Anybody interested in evening meet-up of StackOverflow users in London?

I'm thinking pub, beers and development chatter/discussion - something similar to the old 'Agile Tuesday' meets that used to go on a few years back.

Comment: I would enjoy it immensely if you receive Taxonomist badge for `beer`.

Comment: No love for London, Ontario.

Comment: He may have meant London, ON... I guessed.

Comment: Sure. Although I'm on the other side of the pond for the next few weeks. Just don't pick a pub with excessively loud music (JDWs rock, quietly). (PS: Please don't burgle me when I'm away - at least wait until I come back.)

Comment: @Tom - let's see how much interest we get through London (UK) hours today and if there's a few of us I'll look about for back room of a pub.

Comment: @Tom - take a look at @skaffman's answer.  Drop me a mail too so I can copy you into the chain.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone was looking for an example of why a question should be closed as "***too localized***", look no further...

Comment: Meh, if he only invited people from London, then it would prolly be too localized.  But, since anyone is invited (it seems) I think it is ok.

Comment: @jinguy - always looking for the positives...

Comment: You bet!!  Besides, I would like to be able to post one of these sometime.  So we need to set a precedent in my favor.

Comment: lol - I can't wait to see the post about the upcoming Pony meet and great...

Comment: Yep, anyone and everyone would be welcome :-)

Comment: What is "too localized" anyway? I find jQuery and ASP.NET MVC Framework too localized a topic area because I have nothing to offer and I cannot add anything. I am impotent in these areas; but I am not complaining.

Given it is in London it is obviously for the very large development community that exists here, as well as anybody else who frequents or participates in this (great) community.  I bracket that because there are some that spoil it.  Regardless, I will be going.  It would be good to see you there too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be up for it.

As far as "Agile Tuesday" is concerned, there's still the ["eXtreme Tuesday Club"](http://xpday-london.editme.com/eXtremeTuesdayClub), regularly attended by various luminaries. And there's a lot of beer.

Comment: Cool - I count that as 4 of us, which I reckon could be enough to get something going - presumably we could all bring a gang.

How about you, I, Nick and Tom meet up to discuss (hopefully they'll see these updates) ideas around getting something going?  Mail me on nick.holt@btinternet.com and I'll get a mail chain started.

'eXtreme Tuesday Club' - that's the one, didn't even release it was still happening.  I kind of lost the faith with agile (although it was more of a tech meet-up when I used to go) when I started seeing it treated a just another methodology that was gonna save the day.